# Populating DropDownList from Database with Selected Item

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

Quick question, I have a DropDownList which is being populated from a table in the database called Modules. I then have another table called Functions, in this table I have a field called fn_module.

What I'm trying to do is pull all the data from the Modules table but at the same time check the Functions.fn_module table and make the value on this field the selected value when loading the DropDownList on PageLoad.

Is this possible?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Yes. Everything is possible

Comment: your question is unclear. do you want to bind both the dropdown from a single data-source?

Comment: @Shekhar, if possible yes. I just don't know how to combine both but make the Function.fn_module the selected item when loaded.

Comment: @juanreyesv, how can I make possible? Would u mind providing a an example? Thank you

Comment: will you give some sample code or what have you tried?

Comment: i think you are talking about getting data from 2 tables by a where condition.. isn't it??